# Prevent deletion of .git folder using terminal

Tags: linux, git

I want to delete all the folders and files from my local repo folder, but not the .git folder and any other folder/file proceeding with a '.'.
How exactly do I do that? 
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the following works:

```
git rm -r *
```

That leaves the .gitignore file and any other `.` files unaffected. By default, in bash (and probably other shells) `*` does not match directories or files starting with a `.`.

Similarly,

```
rm * -r -i
```

will only remove files and directories not starting with a `.` with. (remove the -i for non-interactive mode)

Comment: while both our answers are correct, I like yours a lot better because of the bash lesson. It's very true, but not intuitive or commonly known that the wildcard symbol (*) doesn't effect files preceded by the "." symbol. Thank you, martin! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `.git` folder isn't itself version controlled, and Git will not remove it.

Just run `git rm -r .` and you'll remove all files in the repository without removing the `.git` directory.

Comment: But I don't want any file like .gitignore to get deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
find . -type f -not -name ".*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

That will delete all files that aren't preceded with at "."

Please let me know if you have any questions!